Error when creating vector store using Streamlit with langchain
I've been trying to build a chatbot using streamlit, but I've been having an error that I can't understand even though I've tried different things.
traceback: File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 584, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/mount/src/cenace-llm/streamlit_app.py", line 113, in <module>
    main()
File "/mount/src/cenace-llm/streamlit_app.py", line 104, in main
    vectore_store = get_vector_store(chunks)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/mount/src/cenace-llm/streamlit_app.py", line 55, in get_vector_store
    vector_store = FAISS.from_documents(chunks, embeddings)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_core/vectorstores.py", line 550, in from_documents
    return cls.from_texts(texts, embedding, metadatas=metadatas, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/faiss.py", line 965, in from_texts
    embeddings = embedding.embed_documents(texts)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_community/embeddings/ollama.py", line 204, in embed_documents
    embeddings = self._embed(instruction_pairs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_community/embeddings/ollama.py", line 192, in _embed
    return [self._process_emb_response(prompt) for prompt in iter_]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_community/embeddings/ollama.py", line 192, in <listcomp>
    return [self._process_emb_response(prompt) for prompt in iter_]
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_community/embeddings/ollama.py", line 163, in _process_emb_response
    raise ValueError(f"Error raised by inference endpoint: {e}")

This are the functions I'm using and I've been debugging my code but still can't seem to find the problem:
def get_vector_store(chunks):
    """Get vectors for each chunk."""
    embeddings = OllamaEmbeddings(model='gemma:2b')
    st.write(type(chunks),             type(embeddings))
    # builtins.list(iterable=(), /) ,  langchain_community.embeddings.ollama.OllamaEmbeddings
    vector_store = FAISS.from_documents(chunks, embeddings)
    return vector_store

